# how would clojure's reducers work for native javascript objects/arrays?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I only understood a couple of sections in the reducers talk, one which was that a data-structure could implement the `IReducible` interface and be able to transform natively, without being turned into a `LazySeq` first.

I'm hoping to exploit this in clojurescript with native javascript arrays and objects but am not too sure where to start. Can anyone provide an example of how this may be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ClojureScript, the relevant protocol is called `IReduce` and is already implemented for arrays in the standard library. The relevant `extend-type` form is [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/06810b52466467f076519ca590c51833904a6bf7/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L730) (link to the latest commit on master as of right now).

There's also `IKVReduce` used by `reduce-kv`, as well as `clojure.core.reducers/reduce` in the case of map arguments.

You could provide a wrapper for native objects which you'd like to transform in this way:

```
(defn wrap-as-reducible [obj]
  (reify
    IReduce
    (-reduce [this f]
      ...)
    (-reduce [this f init]
      ...)
    IKVReduce
    (-kv-reduce [this f init]
       ...)))
```

Implement either or both of `IReduce` and `IKVReduce` according to your needs.

Directly implementing either protocol for "native objects" in general is probably not a good idea, as that would amount to providing a default case which would render checks for reducibility meaningless etc.

Comment: Thanks michal. I have two questions: Can you elaborate on what happens in the default case for reducibility checks and secondly, what would you suggest I do if I really want to use clojure functions on native objects.... ie (into (array) [1 2 3])

Comment: My point about the default case was that if you provide one for a protocol, then it gets used for any object which doesn't fall under a more specific case, so then even objects of ClojureScript types for which reduce makes no sense given the intended semantics (`Atom`, say) become reducible all of a sudden. As for `(into (array) ...)`, there's `into-array` for that, like in Clojure.

Comment: Ahh okay. So extending objects are not okay. How about arrays? I presume they should be safe to extend with protocols

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the core library provides certain protocol implementations for arrays. You can do that to for your own protocols. Built-in protocols should not be extended to native types in public library code, at least without a big warning to users; this is a special case of the general principle that one should not provide implementations for type/protocol pairs where one does not own at least one of the members of the pair. Anything goes in application code, but you should know the risks. (Most notably, a conflicting implementation might appear in CLJS in the future.)